# Errors reassigning CRS of SpatRaster using terra::projectRaster and raster::project

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, terra

I have the following SpatRaster object called pred_th:

```
dimensions  : 162, 87, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : 43.25, 50.5, -25.58333, -12.08333  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source(s)   : memory
name        :  lyr1 
min value   : FALSE 
max value   :  TRUE
```

I'm trying to reassign the crs to ESPG 29702. When I try the `projectRaster` function from the `terra` package, like this:

```
pred_th %>% 
  projectRaster(crs = "EPSG:29702", method = 'ngb') -> pred_th_proj
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in rbind(xy1, xy2, xy3, xy4, xy5) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 5)
```

When I try the `project` function from the `raster` library, like this:

```
pred_th %>% 
  project(crs = "EPSG:29702", method = 'near') -> pred_th_proj
```

I get this error:

```
Error: [write] unknown option(s): crs
```

Comment: Do you really want the approximation version of the CRS? If you're near the center coordinates of the projection, it's not bad, but it's not very good. Although with a resolution in minutes, it doesn't really matter--never mind!

Answer (score 0):

Your question mixes up the libraries and functions. `projectRaster` is part of `raster` library and `project` is part of `terra`.

I'm not sure what's happening with the `projectRaster` code. It is kind of odd to assign to the right, i.e. code on left and using "`->`", but I don't know if that's the causing the trouble.

I created a mock raster to try to match your example. You were close.

```
# Mock raster
> r1 <- rast(ncol=87,nrow=87, xmin=-43,xmax=50, ymin=-25,ymax=-12)
> crs(r1) <- "epsg:4326"
> r1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 87, 87, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1.068966, 0.1494253  (x, y)
extent      : -43, 50, -25, -12  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 

# Leave out the "crs =". Just provide the value.
> r1 <- r1 %>% project("epsg:29702", method="near")

> r1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 71, 112, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 99990.88, 99990.88  (x, y)
extent      : -10378433, 820545.7, -5535872, 1563480  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Tananarive (Paris) / Laborde Grid approximation (EPSG:29702)
```

Comment: According to `?project` the argument taking `"epsg:29702"` as input  is not `crs`, but `y`. So instead of dropping the name, one could just use the correct one.